# Can't save PDF in API 30 Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-bitmap

This code is working till android 10 but now I want to upgrade it to android 11. I can save the jpeg & even can read the directory but I can't save pdf in android 11. I tried everything on internet but can't find anything. Can someone help me.

> My Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.android.providers.context.permission.WRITE_USE_APP_FEATURE_SURVEY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    

<application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:preserveLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

> My Bitmap function

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bmp) {
    File filename;
     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R){
        try {
            String path1 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + "Documents";
            Log.i("in save()", "after mkdir");
            File file = new File(path1 + "/" + "Premium Scanner/IMAGES");
            if (!file.exists())
                file.mkdirs();
            filename = new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
            Log.i("in save()", "after file");
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            Log.i("in save()", "after outputstream");
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            ContentValues image = getImageContent(filename);
            getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, image);
            createPdf(bmp);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Image saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

> My PDF Function

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
private void createPdf(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R){
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        float hight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        float width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

        int convertHighet = (int) hight, convertWidth = (int) width;

        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
        PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), 1).create();
        PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

        Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        canvas.drawPaint(paint);

        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), true);

        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
        document.finishPage(page);

        // write the document content
        String path1 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + "Documents";
        Log.i("in save()", "after mkdir");
        File file = new File(path1 + "/" + "Premium Scanner/PDF/");
        if (!file.exists())
            file.mkdirs();
        File filepath = new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "FILE_" + timeStamp + ".pdf");
        Log.i("in save()", "after file");
        try {
            document.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(filepath));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something wrong: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        document.close();
    }
}
```

> Image Content Function

```
public ContentValues getImageContent(File parent) {
    ContentValues image = new ContentValues();
    try{
         if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R){
            image.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "IMG_" + timeStamp);
            image.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "IMG_" + timeStamp);
            image.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "App Image");
            image.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis());
            image.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpg");
            image.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.ORIENTATION, 0);
            image.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.BUCKET_ID, parent.toString().toLowerCase().hashCode());
            image.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, parent.getName().toLowerCase());
            image.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, parent.length());
            image.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, parent.getAbsolutePath());
            dismissDialog();
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Image not saved \n" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`
    }

    return image;
}
```

Comment: `if (!file.exists())
                file.mkdirs();` That should be: `if (!file.exists())
               if(!file.mkdirs()) return;` Display a Toast too to inform the user. Please tell what happens.

Comment: `but I can't save pdf in android 11.` What do you mean? You cannot save to file on an Android 11 device?

Comment: `....RELATIVE_PATH, parent.getAbsolutePath())` Dont put an absolute/full path for a relative path.

Comment: You are saving a bitmap to file and a pdf to file. You are not even telling such. And where is the problem.

Comment: `ContentValues image = getImageContent(filename);` Unreadable code. Why do you call that an image and get content? Better: `ContentValues values = getContentValues(filename);`

Comment: `getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.....` That will return an uri. You are doing nothing with the uri.

Comment: @blackapps I can save bitmap but with this bitmap I can't create pdf in android 11 only in API30. I can create directory but can't create create pdf in it.